# Observed service module not included in jpackage

Tags: gluon, jpackage

I use [GluonHQ's backport of jpackager for the JDK 11](https://openjfx-dev.openjdk.java.narkive.com/hHFXGDYo/filling-the-packager-gap), and running it with the `--bind-services` argument:

```
jpackager create-installer -o installer --name "Demo App" --class net.clementlevallois.monitor.Controller --module net.clementlevallois.monitor --module-path lib/ --add-modules net.clementlevallois.monitorobserver --bind-services --win-menu --win-shortcut --win-dir-chooser --strip-native-commands --singleton
```

returns an installer but also throws :

```
Illegal argument [--bind-services]
```

Is it me doing something wrong or is this backport of jpackager effectively not supporting this argument?
My app gets packaged with an installer and I can launch it, but indeed it is supposed to call a service and fails to do so. In this case, how could I package a modular application that includes `ServiceProviders`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you still use this ancient tooling? Instead you should use the new jpackage tool (note the spelling) which was released with JDK 14.

Comment: I know but I have a dependency to a library which is not compatible with JDK 14 (see: https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/955)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I looked into JFoenix too just recently and stopped it immediately when I saw how badly supported it is. But you can still use jpackage for packaging only in conjunction with jlink.

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial which shows how that could work: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: Yes I hesitated as well but material design provides a great UX, and there is no alternative lib for JavaFX. Tough choice.